# How to show popup message in msbot after adding it to a teams channel (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to show a popup message to user asking him to login after adding my bot to teams channel. Like how trello and polly does.Here is the pic of trello how it is asking user to login after adding it to teams channel.
[image]
Is there any way that I can achieve something like that?
Any help would be really thankful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open a popup to allow a user to login you could do that by implementing [Authentication for your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample). If you want to open a popup to show a card/Html page you could try using [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules).

Answer (score 0):

This sample maybe helpful, it shows Auth window

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config